# Populate Spring Bean's File field via Annotation

Tags: spring, file, annotations

Is it possible to do something like this :

```
<property name="template" value="file:/some/resource/path/myTemplate.txt" />
```

via annotations without creating custom annotation and populate the field via reflection ? It cannot be done with @Value, cause it works only with Strings...

If not, what is the best way to process Spring bean custom annotations and init the bean accordingly ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a Resource as the field.

```
@Value("file:/some/resource/path/myTemplate.txt")
Resource template;
```

You can use `classpath:` style URIs this way too.

Then if you need to get a File, use `template.getFile()`

Comment: Cool, btw, do you know how to extend/use AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to inject fields/methods or process them in some way, with custom annotations ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you want to do?

Comment: You maybe use testng - Let say that you have a method abc(a,b,c) that needs be called with some values... I annotate it with @DataProvided annotation and create corresponding DataProvider method ... And I'd want AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to grab the annotation, execute dataprovider method and initialize that abc(a,b,c); method .... It's a nonsense scenario, that can be done by spring normally ... I can't think of anything real now :-) The important point is, get the annotation and do something, whatever you want...

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337128/spring-framework-annotation-question

Comment: You would need to create your own custom `BeanPostProcessor` and have it work like the other `*AnnotationBeanPostProcessor`s.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime

Comment: What is the "templatePath" ? Btw in webapp, If I go like this @Value("${classpath:WEB-INF/classes/exc-msg.properties}") it is not searching on the classpath but from the root of web application context...do you know how to work around it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are trying to set the value of a field which is of type File?  Could you just inject the file name with the @Value and then create the File object in code when needed?

Comment: Not good, File constructor expects absolute or JVM execution path, you usually getting resources from classpath....I'd have to go like  "new File(this.class.getClassLoader.getResource("file").toURI() ); "  ... it's just ugly thing to do ... Spring has nice support like ClassPathResource(String path, ClassLoader classLoader) that could handle it behind the scene

Answer (score -1):

@Value("${file:/some/resource/path/myTemplate.txt}")
Resource template;

Thanks for the wake up, the highly upvoted answer had "templatePath" without any references and now stands corrected - see comments.

The Javadoc or official docs for @Value resource usages was hard to find early 2011 and still is, to find how resources can be injected via @Value spel using classpath, file, url:
[SPEL expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), [File system resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#resources-filesystemresource-caveats), [@Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html), [@PropertyResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

Comment: This should be a comment