# loading a file from classpath

Tags: spring, file, classpath

I have a line of code that is : `File file = new File(getFile())` in a java class `HandleData.java`

Method - `getFile()` takes the value of the property `fileName`. And `fileName` is injected through   `application_context.xml` with a bean section of the class -  HandleData as below:

```
 <bean id="dataHandler" class="com.profile.transaction.HandleData">
 <property name="fileName" value="DataFile.xml"></property>
 </bean>
```

I build the project successfully and checked that - `DataFile.xml` is present in `WEB-INF/classes`. And the HandleData.class is present in `WEB-INF/classes/com/profile/transacon`

But when I run it it throws me filenotfound exception.
  If I inject the absolute path (`C:\MyProjectWorkspace\DataProject\target\ProfileService\WEB-INF\classes\DataFile.xml` it finds the file successfully.).

Could someone help in figuring out the proper path to be injected so that the file is taken from the classpath ?

Answer (score 38):

While injecting a `File` is generally the preferred approach, you can also leverage Spring's ResourceLoader for dynamic loading of resources.

Generally this is as simple as injecting the `ResourceLoader` into your Spring bean:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

Then to load from the classpath:

```
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have:

```
<property name="fileName" value="classpath:DataFile.xml" />
```

And it should be injected as a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486582/516433)

Comment: Hi did you mean <property name="fileName" value="classpath:DataFile.xml" />

Comment: I actually tried that, it shows me FileNotFoundException as classpath:DataFile.xml cannot be found.

Comment: @Steer360, are you sure?  `classpath:DataFile.xml` says find DataFile.xml in the root of anything in the classpath of which WEB-INF/classes is one element...

Comment: yes. The line -  File file = new File(getFile()) is called.So it is getting the value classpath:DataFile.xml now. I just checked with a print statement.

Comment: Thanks lucas, Creating new file or getResourceAsStream takes file name as parameter , i think thats why it does not recognise classpath: with it? I have used classpath:  with the filename for    annotation of @ContextConfiguration or other reference to the file through Context annotation though...

Comment: @Steer360, I updated my answer to include a reference to another answer that shows the code side of this approach

Comment: Thanks , I will try that out, will love to refer classpath:filename from spring injection.

Answer (score 3):

Since OP is injecting Only the fileName through spring, still want to create the File Object through code ,
You should Use ClassLoadeer to read the file

Try this

```
InputStream is =  HandleData.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFile()));
```

**Edit**

Heres the remainder of code , to read the file

```
BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(is);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bf);

while (dis.available() != 0) {
    System.out.println(dis.readLine());
}
```

**Edit 2**

Since you want it as File Object,  to get hold of the FileInputStream

try this

```
 FileInputStream fisTargetFile = new FileInputStream(new File(HandleData.class.getClassLoader().getResource(getFile()).getFile()));
```

Comment: OP is injecting Only the fileName through spring, He would still want to create the File Object through code

Comment: I am trying to use your suggestion and use InputStream instead. Currently I am passing the fileName as below:                   FileInputStream fisTargetFile = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));  So InputStream does not work for this piece.

Comment: Yes. It worked! Could not use classpath:DataFile.xml (I am surprised) in the property value. I think that works when we refer the context with annotation. So I kept the value as "DataFile.xml". I used InputStream is =  HandleData.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFile())); and passed is to the calling method which is IOUtils from org.apache.commons.io and takes InputStream Parameter as well !! Thanks a lot.