# Resource file can not be found

Tags: java, spring

As discussed https://stackoverflow.com/a/22632251/379235, I added my code as

```
  @Value("classpath:lpLogCompressFileLocations")
  private Resource logLocations;
```

and use it as

```
  Compressor getCompressor() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("logLocationsFileExists:" + logLocations.getFile().exists());
    return new Compressor(".", logLocations.getFile(), ZIP_NAME_PREFIX);
  }
```

in my jar file I can locate this file as well

```
$ jar -tvf target/original-Processor.jar  | grep lpLog
    60 Wed Apr 15 12:19:02 PDT 2015 lpLogCompressFileLocations
```

But when I deploy this code and try to access, I get

```
15 Apr 2015 12:17:56,530 [DEBUG] [http-bio-8443-exec-3] ReportSender             | Error in starting compression: class path resource [lpLogCompressFileLocations] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/shn/lp/original-LogProcessor.jar!/lpLogCompressFileLocations
```

I also tried changing my code to

```
@Value("classpath:/lpLogCompressFileLocations")
private Resource logLocations;
```

But the error is same

```
15 Apr 2015 12:19:30,984 [DEBUG] [http-bio-8443-exec-1] ReportSender             | Error in starting compression: class path resource [lpLogCompressFileLocations] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/shn/lp/original-LogProcessor.jar!/lpLogCompressFileLocations
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a file handler to resource existing within a jar file. It is explained here. [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

I am not sure if this solves your purpose, but you can get access to the content as below.

```
@Value("classpath:lpLogCompressFileLocations")
  private Resource logLocations;
```

Within your method(sample code)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.logLocations.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString()); // Prints the string content read from input stream
        reader.close();
```